# outlook 2007 email forwarding questions

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to forward all my emails in outlook 2007 to a gmail account.

I did this the normal way and it worked, but the problem is that my messages get opened since they're being forwarded. I don't want them to appear as read, because if everything shows up as opened right when it comes in, I might miss an important email.

So what I tried to do instead is load my gmail account into outlook. I've tried every possible way to do this. Read everything online. When I hit the test button at the end of the wizard, it always fails.

What happens every time is an outlook dialogue box pops up prompting me to login to my gmail account. When I type in my password and hit login, the box just pops up again. It never goes away no matter how many times I type in the password.

The easiest solution seems be to figuring out a way to set a rule so that the emails get forwarded to my gmail inbox, but don't get opened in my outlook inbox

Anyone know how to fix this?

Update: For whatever reason, setting a redirection rule is not an option. It's simply not on the list of possible items.

Does anyone know the commands to create a custom rule for redirection?

Comment: "I don't want them to appear as unopened" - This means you want them to be appear as read?  I thought that was already the case.

Comment: no sorry I wrote that wrong... I want the messages to appear as unread. redirect is not on the list of options when I make the rule - is there a way to manually set up a redirect since it's not listed?

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Ask your e-mail administrator to redirect the e-mail for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the rule in Outlook to "Redirect" the mail instead of "Forwarding" it.

> The main difference between forwarding and redirection is that while forwarding automatically makes changes to your email and includes details about the message history, redirection discretely sends the email to the intended party in its originally written state, making it appear as if it was received directly from the original sender.

[Blurb Source](http://www.ehow.com/info_12195520_outlook-redirect-vs-forward.html)